# jsch + running multiple command in shell after SU and then close channal

Tags: jsch, su

My requirement is as follow:

I have to login to Unix box using my credentials and once login, I have to do su to different user. I need to provide password and reason for scsu command.
once su successful, I have to run set of commands one after another as that user.

On completion of executions, close channel and session both.

I tried to use Shell channel but I am able to fire scsu only ... need help to complete remaining requirement of executions of command and closing channel

Comment: Nice project, have you tried something?

Comment: yes, i tried shell channel and i was able to do su and able to pass password and reason. then i send command using out.write().... but all my command were passed in one go. though they got executed one after another.   i am facing issue with channel.disconnect as it didn't wait for all command to execute  and it closed connection.

Comment: Please provide a gist (maybe a code snippet) of how you where able to pass the password to the shell for the su command. I'm looking for a solution. http://stackoverflow.com/a/16499330/1917804