# Java ssh: connect to remote, switch user, jump to next host and execute commands

Tags: java, shell, ssh, jsch

I am trying to do these things (using JSch library)...

1. connect to remote host (Host A)
2. switch to some other user
3. connect to other remote host (Host B)
4. execute set of commands with some output

I have success with steps 1 and 4:

```
    Channel channel = session.openChannel("exec");
    channel.setInputStream(null);
    ((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand("whoami");
    channel.connect();
```

This gives me the expected output.
But, when I do something like this, i.e. add number 2:

```
((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand("sudo su - user; whoami");
```

user is not changed.

The other approach I tried is to open "shell" channel but it hangs forever, waiting for the input, I guess. Even if I find a way around that waiting issue, "shell" channel will not be a preferred way to solve this since I need a nicely formatted output of the commands I run - "shell" channel output looks like a real terminal state with all the empty lines, prompt and such things...

Any help will be highly appreciated...

Comment: I guess 'sudo su - user' is expecting to get a password or something, anyway I think ssl tunneling would be an easier solution

Comment: I intentionally omitted password part since it is not causing me troubles.

Comment: I think here is your expected answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16499330/4531116

Comment: Very similar but not a duplicate since here I want to jump from the first host to the third one using authentication on the second.